# HTML <a> tag won't work? Is there an alternative coding tag?

Tags: html, css, atag

I'm using CodePen to create my CIS 101 class final but for some reason, my HTML links won't load. It keeps giving me this: /boomboom/v2/WEBLAB5_HOUSER.html. The homework links on the website are working just fine so I'm wondering if its the tag that I'm using?

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/0n_uh/pen/VweJjBx?editors=1100

HTML FILE: file:///E:/CIS%20-%20101/LABS/WEB%20LAB%20-%2006/WEBLABFINAL_HOUSER/WEBLAB5_HOUSER/WEBLAB5_HOUSER.html

CODE:

```
<html>
  <a href="WEBLAB1_HOUSER.HTML">*Web Lab 1</a>
  <a href="WEBLAB2_HOUSER.html">*Web Lab 2</a>
  <a href="WEBLAB3_HOUSER.html">*Web Lab 3</a>
  <a href="WEBLAB4_HOUSER.html">*Web Lab 4</a>
  <a href="WEBLAB5_HOUSER.html">*Web Lab 5</a>
  <a href="WEBLAB6_HOUSER.html">*Web Lab 6</a>
```

Comment: The problem isn't in the a tag it is in the href attribute. Make sure those files are located in the same directory as the file where the code above is written.

Comment: are you trying to link to another [page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) or link for a [download](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp)?

Comment: also, instead of creating a pen, create a [project](https://blog.codepen.io/2017/03/20/codepen-projects-is-here/). that way you can have multiple html files

Comment: @rhavelka, yes to the first question. My professor wants us to make all of the files linked on one webpage.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov, they're all in the same file on my computer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: hey @0n_uh you can access debug page of your codepen here `https://cdpn.io/0n_uh/debug/VweJjBx` and you can see that relative links doesn't work but lower links will work ok

Comment: If that's what will sufice your need I'd suggest to remove buttons from lower links and that should be fine, or use advice from @rhavelka that you create project and have relative links in projects

Comment: Thank you, @KresimirPendic; I'll try it!

Answer (score 2):

When you don't prepend with a protocol, like `http://`, `file:///`, etc., your browser reads those links as relative (as opposed to absolute) - see https://www.webstix.com/knowledgebase/general/relative-links-vs-absolute-links.

So, if you're on the site https://codepen.io/0n_uh/pen/VweJjBx?editors=1100 and you link to `WEBLAB1_HOUSER.HTML`, your browser will try to open up https://codepen.io/0n_uh/pen/VweJjBx/WEBLAB1_HOUSER.HTML, which presumably doesn't exist.

Change your `href` values to the absolute path, like `<a href="file:///E:/CIS%20-%20101/LABS/WEB%20LAB%20-%2006/WEBLABFINAL_HOUSER/WEBLAB5_HOUSER/WEBLAB5_HOUSER.html">`, and your web browser will open up that file.

**Edit**: note, though, that ideally you'd be using relative links and creating an HTML file that lives alongside your WEBLAB1_HOUSER.HTML file.  That way you'd be able to ship your homepage along with your other pages (WEBLAB1_HOUSER.HTML, etc) in a single zip file.

I'd strongly recommend downloading VSCode and editing your site within there.  It gives you a really nice "preview" feature so you can see your edits in real time.

Comment: Thank you, Taylor! I'll try that.

Comment: hey @Taylor, that link structure `<a href="file://...` will surely not work here - because that local file surely doesn't exist on professors computer — ok

Comment: If it's on the `E:\` drive, it might -- lots of universities map shared drives for their users.
Point taken, though - I'll update my answer to note that ideally relative links would be used.

Comment: I would also add that you could see easier how a browser would route connected files if you were serving the site in your browser.
With python 3 you can run `python -m http.server` in the same folder as your index.html and then see the site on `localhost:8000`